# htaccess mod rewrite not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

My server has an SSL setup on it and it has a site on there viewable in the browser via an IP.

I have an .htaccess file on the root with the following in it:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^single/([^/]*)$ single.php?url=$1 [L]
```

When I view the site URL:

https://100.100.100.100/single/test

I get a 404 not found. I have tried the actual URL:

https://100.100.100.100/single.php?url=test

And that works exactly as it should? Please note that isn't the actual IP

It works perfectly on a shared host. I have checked the server config and the Apache Mod rewrite is enabled.

Comment: Verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting same garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not?

Comment: You're right, I have added a load of random text to the .htaccess file but I still get the 404 and not the 500?

Answer (score 0):

You need the *Query String Appended* flag.

Try:

```
RewriteRule ^single/([^/]+) http://yourdomain.com/single.php?url=$1 [QSA]
```